# Subquery returns more than 1 row, but I want it to

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm trying to run a query on my music database.

The relevant part of my database looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ARTIST (
artistid    integer(3)  auto_increment  not null,
name    varchar(30) not null,
//other columns
CONSTRAINT ALBUM_pk PRIMARY KEY (artistid)
);

CREATE TABLE SONG (
songid  integer(5)  auto_increment  not null,
lineupid    integer(5)  not null,
title   varchar(50) not null,
//other columns
CONSTRAINT SONG_pk PRIMARY KEY (songid),
CONSTRAINT SONG_fk_ARTIST FOREIGN KEY (lineupid)
    REFERENCES ARTISTLINEUPLINEUP (artistlineupid),
CONSTRAINT SONG_fk_GENRE FOREIGN KEY (genreid)
    REFERENCES GENRE (genreid)
);

CREATE TABLE ARTISTLINEUP (
artistlineupid  integer(3)  auto_increment not null,
lineupid    integer(5)  not null,
artistid    integer(3)  not null, 
CONSTRAINT ARTISTLINEUP_pk PRIMARY KEY (artistlineupid),
CONSTRAINT ARTISTLINEUP_fk_ARTIST FOREIGN KEY (artistid)
    REFERENCES ARTIST (artistid),
CONSTRAINT ARTISTLINEUP_fk_LINEUP FOREIGN KEY (lineupid)
    REFERENCES LINEUP (lineupid)
);
```

I'm trying to get all the songs written by one artist, which has multiple lineups.

```
SELECT title
FROM song
WHERE lineupid = (
    SELECT artistlineupid
    FROM artistlineup
    WHERE artistid = (
        SELECT artistid
        FROM artist
        WHERE name = "Black Sabbath"));
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

This is correct, because this artist has multiple lineups and therefore returns two numbers. Why can't it return the songs with both lineupid's? How can I get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: You cannot compare artist id to a set of artist ids. Maybe you want to use IN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can phrase the query in different way, if you want to compare multiple values, use `IN` not `=`:

```
SELECT title
FROM song
WHERE lineupid IN (
    SELECT artistlineupid
    FROM artistlineup
    WHERE artistid IN (
        SELECT artistid
        FROM artist
        WHERE name = "Black Sabbath"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If artistid is unique with respect to name you can also use limit

```
SELECT title
FROM song
WHERE lineupid = (
    SELECT artistlineupid
    FROM artistlineup
    WHERE artistid = (
        SELECT artistid
        FROM artist
        WHERE name = "Black Sabbath" LIMIT 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Write 'IN' Instead of giving '=' symbol in you query.

Means you used the '=' operator 2 times in where clause.so replace that with 'In' and then try the query.

you will get the result.

Thank You,

Phani kumar.